# Listing directory's names with given arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I need to list the names of the directory's folders and files, but starting from `input1` until `input2` (arguments, user's inputs).

```
#!/bin/bash
START_INDEX=$1
END_INDEX=$2
     for $STA_INDEX in $(ls) -le $END_INDEX; do
           echo item: $STA_INDEX
     done
```

Together with my colleague, we came up with this "solution" which is not a solution at all!
So, can anyone try to explain me where I go wrong with this or give me another approach to a working solution. I think this piece of code will give you the main idea.

Comment: What do you mean by 'starting from input1 until input2'? What order do files/folders have?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Given that you were using `-le`, I assume the two inputs are numbers? And you want to list the m-th result to the n-th result of `ls`?

Comment: @doubleDown yup, the inputs are numbers. For example, I have folders in my home directory, starting with MyDocs as first, MyVideos as 2nd and... MyMusic as 8th. What I want to do is the following: As my first input I'm gonna took 2 and as second 7. Now I want the folder's names printed out in that order.

Comment: @Scorpy: in that case anydot's answer seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If indexes you are talking about are indexes in `ls` output you want to start/end, then it's something easy to solve with `sed`:

```
ls | sed -ne "${START_INDEX},${STOP_INDEX}p"
```

How this works: it suppress automatic output from `sed` and then it prints all lines which are in range `<$START_INDEX,$STOP_INDEX>`. You can find more information in `sed` manual, search for range operators.

Comment: To be safe, you should enclose the variable names in braces, i.e. `${START_INDEX},${STOP_INDEX}`

Comment: Good catch, this is even necessary because of the "p" sed command would. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the user is expected to specify two names and you want to list the files that sort between those two names, this script will do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $# in
(2) : OK;;
(*) echo "Usage: $0 from to" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

lo="$1"
hi="$2"
for file in *
do [[ "$file" < "$lo" ]] && continue
   [[ "$file" > "$hi" ]] && break
   echo "$file"
done
```

The `case` checks that the use provided two arguments and bails out with a semi-helpful message if they didn't.  I simply assume that `$lo` compares lower than `$hi`; it would be possible to swap them if not:

```
if [[ "$1" < "$2" ]]
then lo="$1"; hi="$2"
else lo="$2"; hi="$1"
fi
```

Using the `*` (glob) avoids problems with spaces (etc) in file names.  Parsing the output of `ls` is error prone because of spaces (etc) in file names.  The tests use `[[` so that you can do lexicographical ordering of strings; the classic `[` test operator does integer comparisons with the `-lt` notation and only supports `=` and `!=` for string comparisons.

The names in the glob are in sorted order, so the first condition skips names that come before the `$lo` entry; once the `$hi` is too small, you don't need to process the other files (hence break).  Otherwise, you print the name.

The loop is written very compactly; it could be written slightly less compactly with `if`, `elif` and `else`.

```
for file in *
do
    if [[ "$file" < "$lo" ]]
    then continue
    elif [[ "$file" > "$hi" ]]
    then break
    else echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

---

Given a directory listing:

```
cmp.sh        human_numbers.pl  intapprox.pl  lg.c    lu    makefile  x
fibonacci.pl  idsdb00216213.ec  lg            lg.out  lu.c  unget.c   x.c
```

running `bash cmp.sh garbage rubbish` produces:

```
human_numbers.pl
idsdb00216213.ec
intapprox.pl
lg
lg.c
lg.out
lu
lu.c
makefile
```

That agrees with what I'd expect, given my interpretation of your slightly loosely-worded question.  Note that neither `garbage` nor `rubbish` is the name of a file in the directory but it still works.

Comment: There's no `>=` operator, but you can use `<` and `||`:
for file in *
do [[ "$file" > "$hi" ]] && break
   [[ "$file" < "$lo" ]] || echo "$file"
done

Comment: Bah, I forgot you can't format comments. I hope you get the idea though.

Comment: That's an interesting observation (that there are no `<=` or `>=` operators to `[[`), but it isn't very important since the code shown doesn't try to use them (more by good luck than serious design, as it happens, but nonetheless, it doesn't use them).

Comment: I was really just trying to simplify `[[ "$file" < "$lo" ]] && continue; echo "$file"` and in the end I achieved it by replacing the `&& continue;` with `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Something (basic) like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

for x in $*
do
  ls -l $x
done


$./args.sh dir1 dir2 ...
```